# Sphinx in Rails - ERROR: index 'user_core': sql_connect: FATAL: role "root" does not exist

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, sphinx, thinking-sphinx

When I run rake ts:index, I get the following error:

```
Generating Configuration to /Users/main/rails_projects/glassboard/config/development.sphinx.conf
Sphinx 2.0.4-release (r3135)
Copyright (c) 2001-2012, Andrew Aksyonoff
Copyright (c) 2008-2012, Sphinx Technologies Inc (http://sphinxsearch.com)

using config file '/Users/main/rails_projects/glassboard/config/development.sphinx.conf'...
indexing index 'user_core'...
ERROR: index 'user_core': sql_connect: FATAL:  role "root" does not exist
 (DSN=pgsql://root:***@localhost:5432/glassboard_development).
total 0 docs, 0 bytes
total 0.005 sec, 0 bytes/sec, 0.00 docs/sec
skipping non-plain index 'user'...
total 0 reads, 0.000 sec, 0.0 kb/call avg, 0.0 msec/call avg
total 0 writes, 0.000 sec, 0.0 kb/call avg, 0.0 msec/call avg
```

There's nothing online about this error I can find, what problem does Sphinx have with my database?

My OS is Mac 10.6.8 and I'm using (PostgreSQL) 9.1.4.

Comment: It's trying to connect as the user `root` and there  isn't one. Connect as a user that exists for your database.

Comment: Any idea how I can do that?  I'm trying the instructions from - http://articles.slicehost.com/2009/5/7/postgresql-creating-and-deleting-roles but I get ERROR:  permission denied to create role
 even though I su into an admin account

Comment: You must be connected as a PostgreSQL superuser or a user with `CREATEROLE` rights to create users. The account you think is admin isn't. On a typical install you'd use the `postgres` account, but you've told us nothing about your OS, Pg install, Pg version, etc.

Comment: My OS is Mac 10.6.8 and I'm using (PostgreSQL) 9.1.4., what other information would you need?  I didn't create a postgres account, you're saying I need to create a new user on my Mac with the name postgres?  Is there any way I can make my standard login account a Postgres superuser?

Comment: The problem I had re dealing with superusers was solved here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15791406/logged-in-as-postgres-but-getting-the-error-createuser-creation-of-new-role-fai

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What version of Thinking Sphinx are you using? There was a bug quite some time ago that presumed the default database user was root if it wasn't specified (appropriate for MySQL, but not for PostgreSQL), but that was fixed. I'd recommend updating to the latest appropriate version for whatever Rails you're using (Rails 2: TS 1.4.14, Rails 3: TS 2.0.14).

Or you could update to TS 3.0.2 if you're on Rails 3.1 or newer - but there's significant changes there: http://pat.github.com/thinking-sphinx/upgrading.html