# Logged in as postgres but getting the error createuser: creation of new role failed: ERROR: must be superuser to create superusers

Tags: postgresql, psql

I need to create a superuser so I can create a db, but I'm having trouble with this.  I'm logged in as the user postgres:

```
sudo su - postgres
```

But when I try to create a superuser, I get the following problem:

```
$createuser glassboard;
Shall the new role be a superuser? (y/n) y
```

createuser: creation of new role failed: ERROR:  must be superuser to create superusers

This also happens if I try to create a new user in psql and then make him a superuser:

```
$ psql -U postgres
psql (9.1.4)
Type "help" for help.

postgres=> create user glassboard
postgres-> ;
ERROR:  permission denied to create role
```

How do I create a superuser?

output of `\du` in postgres:

```
postgres=> \du

                             List of roles
 Role name |                   Attributes                   | Member of 
-----------+------------------------------------------------+-----------
 main      | Superuser, Create role, Create DB, Replication | {}
 postgres  |                                                | {}
```

Comment: Apparently your `postgres` user is not superuser which is weird. When you're inside psql, can you issue `\du` add the output to your question? I suspect you're using some OSX package such as `postgres.app` with non-standard defaults compared to Unix.

Comment: I added this info to my question.  How can I give the account postgres superuser status?  When I run $ psql -U main, I get
psql: FATAL:  database "main" does not exist

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Some OSX packages don't create a `postgres` superuser database account. The superuser is named differently, in your case it's `main`.

When you do `psql -U main` without specifying a database, it defaults to the same name as the user.
If you don't have a database named `main`, indicate a different database with the `-d` option.

If you have no database to connect to, use `template1`

```
psql -U main -d template1
```

If still you want to grant superuser to `postgres`, do once logged inside psql:

```
alter user postgres superuser;
```

Comment: Exactly what I was about to type, except that recent versions of Postgres (at least since 9.0, I think) create a completely empty database called `postgres` by default, which should be used rather than `template1` as a place to run administrative commands.

Comment: Thanks a lot Daniel, and I did use postgres as a the default db rather than template1.

Answer (score 5):

In my case on PostgreSQL 9.2, the `postgres` superuser was created, but when I went to create additional superusers from the `postgres` user, I was never prompted with `Shall the new role be a superuser? (y/n)` so the new user was created with default permissions. To fix this, I just ran this command as the `postgres` user: `ALTER USER myuser WITH SUPERUSER;`

Answer (score 5):

## On Mac OS default installation

The default superuser is not `postgres`, but the current mac-os user. In order to solve that:

1 . Connect to your DB with your current (system) user. The below example connects to DB named "postgres":

```
psql -d postgres
```

you should get into psql prompt, like *`postgres=#`*

2 . Grant superuser to well-known `postgres` username:

```
ALTER ROLE postgres superuser;
```

If everything went smoothly, you'll see the response: *`ALTER ROLE`*

3 . Enjoy! *(***`\q`** *to quit)*

Answer (score 1):

I am using PostgreSQL 9.6 (not saying my solution shouldn't work for older or newer versions) on macOS Sierra (10.12.2) and what really worked for me was to create another user with the following command line:

```
createuser -s anotheruser
```

Answer (score -2):

Had the same issue about not being able to create a new user, after creating a database and logging into that database as the superuser.

This is what worked for me (unfortunately I didn't have time to study the why), on Debian 10, Postgresql12

Log into the system default db (postgres) as the default superuser (in my case I had just installed it, so).

psql -d postgres

and then I was able to create the user, with exactly the same command line that didn't work when I was logged under the database I had created:
create user xxxx with password 'yyyyyy';

Then I granted all on the new database that I had created

grant all on database newly_created_database to xxxx;